# What is causing my MERN Heroku Deployment Issue?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I have tried a variety of different steps to try to get my MERN app to deploy to Heroku, but I keep getting this error message:

```
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! myapp@0.0.1 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.1 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.nMEIY/_logs/2021-08-20T03_33_48_241Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! myapp@10.0.0 build: `cd client && npm install && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@10.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.nMEIY/_logs/2021-08-20T03_33_48_263Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 40c9b9c5eefeea275c0f5c3ab622d7ed8a1e83fd
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 40c9b9c5eefeea275c0f5c3ab622d7ed8a1e83fd
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to myapp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

I have tried virtually every solution I could find here on stack overflow to no avail. My file structure is like so:

```
myproject
    |----- client
    |        | ---- build
    |        | ---- package.json
    |----- src
    |        | ---- package.json
    |        | ---- index.js
    |----- index.js
    |----- package.json
```

And my root package.json is:

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "10.0.0",
    "description": "myapp",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "nodemon index.js",
        "start:prod": "node index.js",
        "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd ./src && npm install",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build"
    },
    "author": "CORGIRAPTORSAPP",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "mongoose": "^5.7.5",
        "password-generator": "^2.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "^1.18.2"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "14.16.1"
    }
}
```

I have tried many different things including committing to a different branch, reinstalling packages, deleting lock files and other things. At this point it doesn't seem to do anything. When I run heroku local everything seems to work fine so I'm at a loss.

Comment: This isn't a Git issue: `git push` just sends your commits to another repository, where Heroku grabs them, tries to compile them, and then tries to deploy them. Any errors along the way are *from* Heroku and Git simply relays them back to you. Git is therefore only the messenger. **If** (big if) you can get that file, `/tmp/npmcache.nMEIY/_logs/2021-08-20T03_33_48_263Z-debug.log`, it probably has useful information in it.

Comment: Could it be that you are missing the node version in the child project package.json?

Comment: Ill try that Hamza

Comment: Added the engine to every available package.json. Nothing